# 給料を 下げられた vs 引き下げられた

Tags: nuances, word-usage

> - 給料を下げられた。
> - 給料を引き下げられた。

この二つの文は意味として違いますか？
どちらの方が使いますか？

Answer (score 2):

They are basically interchangeable. In formal documents or such, 引き下げ would be preferred, but when you casually refer to your own salary, they would make almost no difference.